Github Secrets & Azure Deployment for ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I have stored my JWT_SECRETS and DB_CONNECTION string in github secrets, now when I deployed the app to Azure, I get an error http 500 Azure
Also when I launched the ASP.NET Core 8 Web API locally with the keys using the launchsettings.json file, it's working fine.
I think I'm not able to properly connect the Github secrets with the Azure deployed app.
This is my yml
name: Publish

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
    - main

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: my-gym
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: "./publish"

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: "8.0.100"

    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore ./mygym.sln

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build ./mygym.sln --configuration Release --no-restore

    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish ./mygym.sln --configuration Release --no-build --output '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
      env:
        SMS_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SMS_CLIENT_SECRET }}
        SMS_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.SMS_CLIENT_ID }}
        JWT_AUDIENCE: ${{ secrets.JWT_AUDIENCE }}
        JWT_ISSUER: ${{ secrets.JWT_ISSUER }}
        JWT_REFRESH_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET }}
        JWT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
        DB_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{ secrets.DB_CONNECTION_STRING }}

    - name: Deployment
      uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
      env:
        SMS_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SMS_CLIENT_SECRET }}
        SMS_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.SMS_CLIENT_ID }}
        JWT_AUDIENCE: ${{ secrets.JWT_AUDIENCE }}
        JWT_ISSUER: ${{ secrets.JWT_ISSUER }}
        JWT_REFRESH_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET }}
        JWT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
        DB_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{ secrets.DB_CONNECTION_STRING }}

I manually added the keys in the environment variable -> app settings and connection strings in azure deployed app service still it's not working.

I created a sample ASP .Net core 8 Web API and successfully stored secrets in GitHub secrets.

I've added the below lines to my yml file, it Sets environment variables in the Azure Web App using the Azure CLI command. These variables are fetched from GitHub Secrets.
So, there is no need to add secrets manually in your Azure Web App.

- name: Set environment variables for Azure Web App
 run: |
   az webapp config appsettings set --name kawebapp6 --resource-group v-kaslesha-mindtree --settings JwtSettings__Secret="${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}" JwtSettings__Issuer="${{ secrets.JWT_ISSUER }}" ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="${{ secrets.DB_CONNECTION_STRING }}"

My complete workflow file:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - kawebapp6
on:  
push:  
branches:  
 - master  
workflow_dispatch:
jobs:  
build:  
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:  
 - uses: actions/checkout@v4
 - name: Set up .NET Core  
uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4  
with:  
dotnet-version: '8.x'
 - name: Build with dotnet  
run: dotnet build --configuration Release
 - name: dotnet publish  
run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ./myapp
 - name: Upload artifact for deployment job  
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4  
with:  
name: .net-app  
path: ./myapp
deploy:  
runs-on: windows-latest  
needs: build  
environment:  
name: 'Production'  
url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}  
permissions:  
id-token: write
steps:  
 - name: Download artifact from build job  
uses: actions/download-artifact@v4  
with:  
name: .net-app    
 - name: Login to Azure  
uses: azure/login@v2  
with:  
client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<client-key> }}  
tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<tenant-key> }}  
subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<subscription-key> }}
 - name: Deploy to Azure Web App  
id: deploy-to-webapp  
uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3  
with:  
app-name: 'kawebapp6'  
slot-name: 'Production'  
package: .  
 - name: Set environment variables for Azure Web App  
run: |  
az webapp config appsettings set --name kawebapp6 --resource-group v-kaslesha-mindtree --settings JwtSettings__Secret="${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}" JwtSettings__Issuer="${{ secrets.JWT_ISSUER }}" ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="${{ secrets.DB_CONNECTION_STRING }}"


Make sure to add the correct secrets in GitHub Secrets section of your repository.


I've successfully deployed the app to Azure Web App via GitHub actions.

Here, secrets are directly added as environment variables to my Azure Web App.


Thanks, but in my case when I saw my deployed app I only have subscription id there was no client & tenant id I need that to perform login to azure in the yml. I checked it said i have to register the app but when it's asking to create a new app. Not able to register my already deployed app hence no client or tenant id.
